# iOS with or without cryptography

Tags: ios, https, appstore-approval

I have created a simple iOS based app with a button. On clicking the button, the app opens an https link to open a page in Safari web browser. I want to upload the app to the app store, however while uploading the details, I am asked if it has cryptography. I want to know if I need to answer Yes or No.

Thanks.

Comment: So how should I distribute such a simple app to my customers if they need one? @Shubhank

Comment: I asked Apple in person and was told that accessing a HTTPS site does not require answering YES.